# Angular Route Infinite Loop

Tags: angularjs, infinite-loop, routes

For some reason when I have a dynamic property in my route and access that page I get stuck in an infinite loop where that page will continuously request itself.

```
.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "pages/index.html",
        controller: "IndexCtrl"
    }).when("/listhome", {
        templateUrl: "pages/listhome.html",
        controller: "ListHomeCtrl"
    }).when("/profile", {
        templateUrl: "pages/profile.html",
        controller: "ProfileCtrl"
    }).when("/newlist", {
        templateUrl: "pages/newlist.html",
        controller: "NewListCtrl"
    }).when("/userlists/:id", {
        templateUrl: "pages/userlists.html",
        controller: "UserListsCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
```

The route I'm looking at is the /userlists/:id route. The controller for that route is-

```
TopTenApp.controller("UserListsCtrl", ["$scope","$routeParams", function($scope, $routeParams)
{
    console.log($routeParams);
    $scope.lists = [];
}]);
```

And when I access /userlists/9 I see-

```
Object {id: "9"}
```

Being logged every 3 seconds and the page freezes. This seems to happen whenever there is a forward slash after the location ("/userslists/" instead of "/userlists").

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: Which server you use? how is it setup?

Comment: Another problem I'm having is that if I got to /userlists/9 directly through the address bar and not through a link on the site the entire page's html contents is alerted. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Forget I said anything. Another logic issue- not angularjs related.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Silly me I realized the problem. I guess it makes sense but the template url needs to have a forward slash in front of it when the page is multiple "directories" deep.

```
.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/index.html",
        controller: "IndexCtrl"
    }).when("/listhome", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/listhome.html",
        controller: "ListHomeCtrl"
    }).when("/profile", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/profile.html",
        controller: "ProfileCtrl"
    }).when("/newlist", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/newlist.html",
        controller: "NewListCtrl"
    }).when("/userlists/:id", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/userlists.html",
        controller: "UserListsCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
}]);
```

Hopefully that helps someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks! Also make sure you also update the paths in your ng-includes.

Comment: This just solved a similar problem of mine (after I spent more time on it than I'd like to admit). Thanks!

Comment: Same here, the problem was a misspell templateUrl. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting 404 (Not Found) error when adding a forward slash.

Comment: @AJ_83 It largely depends on how your urls are setup.

Comment: Problem solved. I got:                 //when('/', {
                //    templateUrl: 'index.html',
                //    controller: 'controllerA'
                //}). PLUS                 otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                }); in my config file. Deleted first one.

Comment: Thank you man, I am just wondering how you figured it out, I spend a lot of time , and almost getting crazy :) just to add , if you have images or links in your page , they also need to have forward slash in front