# Route with Arguments and Resolve Loads Angular More Than Once

Tags: angularjs, express, angularjs-routing, mean-stack

This is working code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker) that receives and renders the data.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/matches', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/matches',
        controller: MyCtrl,
        resolve: MyCtrl.resolve
    });
});

function MyCtrl($scope, datasets, $log) {
    $scope.datasets = datasets.data;
    $log.info(datasets.data[0]);
}

MyCtrl.resolve = {
    datasets : function($http) {
        return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/matches/Orioles' });
    }
};
```

But when I add the route params like

```
$routeProvider.when('/matches/:team', ...

MyCtrl.resolve = {
    datasets : function($http, $route) {
    var link = 'api/matches/' + $route.current.params.team;
    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: link });
  }
};
```

It start acting like some  loop or recursion. Try to load Angular multiple times and the browser freezes

```
GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js?_=1408235258856 200 12ms - 241.55kb
GET /vendor/angular/angular.js?_=1408235258857 200 27ms - 759.52kb
GET /vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js?_=1408235258858 200 23ms - 23.74kb
GET /vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js?_=1408235258859 200 2ms - 32.28kb
GET /app/app.js?_=1408235258860 200 1ms - 2.24kb
GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js?_=1408235258861 200 1ms - 241.55kb
GET /vendor/angular/angular.js?_=1408235258862 200 3ms - 759.52kb
GET /vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js?_=1408235258863 200 3ms - 23.74kb
GET /vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js?_=1408235258864 200 3ms - 32.28kb
GET /app/app.js?_=1408235258865 200 1ms - 2.24kb
GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js?_=1408235258866 200 1ms - 241.55kb
GET /vendor/angular/angular.js?_=1408235258867 200 11ms - 759.52kb
GET /vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js?_=1408235258868 200 2ms - 23.74kb
GET /vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js?_=1408235258869 200 1ms - 32.28kb
GET /app/app.js?_=1408235258870 200 1ms - 2.24kb
GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js?_=1408235258871 200 2ms - 241.55kb
```

Comment: It's probably a problem with html5Mode, which server you run on?

Comment: @IlanFrumer you are just the one I need, 'cause I study and use MEAN

Comment: show your server side code

Comment: @qm69 same problem here, did you figure this out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular Route Infinite Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356671/angular-route-infinite-loop)